# Как правильно написать сервер на сокетах?

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    playerses = new ArrayList<>();
    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(7475);
    while (true) {
        Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    while (true) {
                        String asd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream())).readLine();
                        System.out.println(asd);
                    }
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

Нужно сделать так, чтобы сервер после того, как к нему подключится клиент по сокету, начинал его слушать.

`while(true)` - это не плохой код? На производительность влиять не будет? Память потребляет, питание на ноутбуке ест? Или есть другой способ?

Comment: Есть - использовать netty.

Comment: @Suvitruf, это метод такой чтоли? в socket я не нашел что  - то

Comment: Это библиотека http://netty.io/ . Нет никаких причин писать сервер на голых сокетах руками, если у вас мало в этом опыта и вы заботитесь о производительностии на продакшене.

Comment: Во-первых, культурнее выражаться - тут всё же официальная обстановка. Во-вторых, магическую константу `7475` вынести в `private static final`, а первый `while (true)` заменить хотя бы на `while (isWorking)`, предварительно объявив переменную. Пользы это не даст, так как поток всё равно блокируется на `.accept()` и для прерывания основного потока имеет смысл закрывать серверный сокет, а не просто делать `isWorking = false`, но всё же. В-третьих, `BufferedReader` создать один раз, в начале `run`. В-четвертых, внутренний `while (true)` тоже стоит преобразовать, чтобы появилось условие завершения.

Comment: ок спс всем....

Comment: Слушайте, а правильно ли то что я для каждого пользователя создаю свой поток? может взять 5 пользователей в один поток запихать?

Comment: `while (true)` всегда стоит заменять на, как минимум, `while (!Thread.currentThread.isInterrupted())`. В один поток вы никак не запихнете пять пользователей, потому что в одном потоке у вас одна линия выполнения, и вы не сможете мультиплицировать обработку пользователей, потому что так или иначе обработка каждого из них будет различаться. Однако выделение потока на запрос - не единственная архитектура, есть, например, т.н. event loop, который постоянно смотрит, сколько новых клиентов пришло, и пытается их синхронно обработать - там вообще только один поток используется.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не вижу ничего особенно плохого в вашем коде.

Написание собственного велосипедного сервера — шаг, через который стоит пройти.

Из минусов — выделение потока на каждый клиент. Это потенциально приведёт к невозможности обработки, скажем, 10000 клиентов одновременно. В братском .NET проблема решается при помощи паттерна async/await, в Java, судя по всему, вам придётся поддерживать состояние работы с каждым из клиентов вручную.

Затем, если ваш сервер на деле использует более высокоуровневый протокол (HTTP?) имеет смысл воспользоваться готовым клиентом, правильный разбор высокоуровневых сложных протоколов — та ещё задача. Хотя да, этот клиент будет делать по сути примерно то же самое.

Comment: 10000 клиентов одновременно невозможно обработать ни на каком фреймворке, ни на .Net, ни на Netty - просто потому, что пока не существует 10000-ядерных машин.

Comment: @rfq, [например](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tornado)

Comment: @rfq, а зачем каждому клиенту целое ядро? Nodejs замечательно 10К держит. .NET а тасками - вроде тоже.

Comment: Если клиентов К больше чем ядер С, то (К-С) клиентов не обрабатываются, а ждут в очереди. И неважно, на каком этапе они ждут - на стадии подключения или на стадии обработки.

Comment: 10000 ядер на одного пользователя?

А как тогда справляются игровые серверы?, по сравнении с моей прогой, где инфа будет передавать через каждые 2-3 минуты, то в игровых вообще каждую милисек. передаются, а там людей больше 

500 000.

Comment: @rfq: Смотрите. Совершенно не обязательно на каждого клиента расходовать поток. .NET с async/await прекрасно обходится без этого — ожидание сетевого ответа и чтения с диска там не блокирует поток, а позволяет использовать его для обработки следующего клиента в очереди. Это можно реализовать и без async/await, но придётся вручную поддерживать список заданий и состояние запросов.

Comment: @Vlad Я о чем и говорю. Зачем сразу же создавать поток вновь подключившемуся пользователю, если этот поток все равно будет ждать в очереди к процессору. Можно задержаться перед serverSocket.accept() пока число потоков (обратываемых соединений) не уменьшиться до количества ядер. Для этого удобно воспользоваться семафором - головной поток опускает семафор, закончившаяся обработка запроса поднимает. Начальное значение availableProcessors().

Comment: @rfq: Ну просто вы говорите, что 10К клиентов одновременно обработать невозможно. Мне кажется, если под _одновременной_ обработкой понимать _параллельную_ — то есть, сначала пришёл первый клиент, потом пришёл второй клиент, потом третий и т. д., потом первый получил что хотел и ушёл, и при этом процесс обработки запроса всех 10К не стоит в ожидании первых 4, то это вполне достижимо.

Comment: @VladD
А будет ли уместным для тысяч соединений использовать ForkJoin для многопоточности?

Comment: @CodeGust: У меня нету опыта с ForkJoin, спросите лучше у спецов по Java. Я в основном дотнетчик.