# Java консольный сервер, обрабатывающий запросы всех доступных сетевых интерфейсов

Tags: java, сокет, клиент-сервер, интерфейс, tcp

TCP v4 cервер должен обслуживать соединения на всех доступных сетевых интерфейсах с кодировкой протокола ASCII.
Сервер принимает запрос и отсылает обратно данные. Порт указан.

Самое близкое, что несколько наталкивает на решение - https://stackoverflow.com/a/28232260

Сейчас мой код просто отсылает данные обратно на принятый запрос:

```
try (Socket socket = new ServerSocket(getPort()).accept()) {
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        while (true) {
                            try (BufferedReader getString = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.US_ASCII));
                                 DataOutputStream sendString = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());  ) { 
                                sendString.write(autocomplete(getString.readLine()).getBytes("US-ASCII"));
                            } catch (IOException e) { Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e.getMessage()); }
                        }
                    }
                }).start();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) { Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex.getMessage()); }
```

Для ExecutorService:

```
final ExecutorService service = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
    service.submit(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try (Socket socket = new ServerSocket(init()).accept();
            BufferedReader fromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.US_ASCII));
            DataOutputStream outToClient = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());) { 
                outToClient.write(autocomplete(fromClient.readLine()).getBytes("US-ASCII"));
            } catch (IOException e) { 
                service.shutdown(); 
                Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e.getMessage()); 
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Как можно осуществить данную функциональность прослушивания всех сет.интерфейсов?

Каким способом лучше реализовать меогопоточность для поддержки многих клиент-соединений:

- как можно улучшить мой код?
- будет ли использование ExecutorService более производительным?
- будет ли уместным для тысяч соединений использовать ForkJoin для многопоточности?

Comment: так-то конструктор `ServerSocket(int port)` создает сокет, принимающий подключение со всех интерфейсов. По "как лучше" тут уже [спрашивали](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/470017/).

Comment: @zRrr
Спасибо. А будет ли уместным для тысяч соединений использовать ForkJoin для многопоточности?
Как задать кодировку ascii для сокета?

Comment: Про тысячи соединений - без понятия. Кодировка появляется, когда вы переходите от байтов, которые гоняются по сети, к символам. В класса java это переход от `InputStream` к `Reader`, т.е. `InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8 );` будет возвращать символы, полученные из входящего потока байтов с помощью кодировки UTF8.